# Android Exoplayer SimpleExoPlayerView Play/Pause events

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

Is there a way to hook into the Play/Pause click events of the SimpleExoPlayerView controls? I'm trying to hookup chromecast to my play activity and i need to be able to respond to play events to determine if exoplayer should play the content or it should be sent to chromecast.

I thought onPlayerStateChanged might help with this but i can't see a ExoPlayer.STATE_PLAYING state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView)findViewById(R.id.simpleExoView);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setControlDispatcher(new PlaybackControlView.ControlDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(ExoPlayer exoPlayer, boolean b) {

            // implement what you need

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchSeekTo(ExoPlayer exoPlayer, int i, long l) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: In theory this should solve my problem but its not pretty. I was hoping to implement something like the State Machine in the chromecast demo app https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#1. That aside this only partly works. The demo app uses ExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady during onStart but this bypasses the SimpleExoPlayerView dispatchSetPlayWhenReady we set. The only time dispatchSetPlayWhenReady is hit is after it initially loads and the play button is hit. And i don't see a SimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayWhenReady that would dispatch to the underlying ExoPlayer

Comment: Ok i had to do dig though the SimpleExoPLayerView source but i think i found a work around. It seems the play buttons use            mSimpleExoPlayerView.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY)); which will delegate to the controlDispatcher.setPlayWhenReady

Answer (score 2):

> in XML

```
           <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bgFrag">

            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/playerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:use_controller="true"
                app:controller_layout_id="@layout/item_player_controler"
                app:keep_content_on_player_reset="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:resize_mode="zoom"
                app:shutter_background_color="@color/transperent">


            </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
            

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivExoPlayPause"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play" />
</<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> item_player_controler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@id/exo_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:button="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
       />

    <ImageView android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:button="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

> in Java

```
videoviewholder.playerview.findViewById(R.id.exo_play).setOnClickListener(view->{
                    ToastUtils.showShort("play");
                    videoviewholder.videoItemBinding.ivExoPlayPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    videoviewholder.videoItemBinding.playerview.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(true);
    
                });

   videoviewholder.playerview.findViewById(R.id.exo_pause).setOnClickListener(view->{
                    ToastUtils.showShort("pause");
                    videoviewholder.videoItemBinding.ivExoPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    videoviewholder.videoItemBinding.playerview.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(false);
    
                });
    
                videoviewholder.playerview.setControllerAutoShow(true);
                videoviewholder.playerview.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(0);
                videoviewholder.playerview.setControllerHideOnTouch(false);
                videoviewholder.playerview.setPlayer(player);
```